# Vertical or Top alignment in card UI design

Tags: alignment

I need your advice

Which is better in card UI design Vertical align or top align ?

### **Vertical align** Preview

[image]

### *or*

### **Top align** Preview

[image]
As you can see, some cards with 2 lines text and some of them with 1 line text

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the vertical-align is that the eye trajectory will bend, which require to focus more.
[image]

With top alignment, you will provide a straight and solid eye trajectory, which is easier for quick-scan. The only issue is that with your current layout two lines of text look like vertically aligned. I would suggest decreasing margin-top to make it look consistent. This would also allow having more lines of text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The vertical align preview looks better based on when the texts is two lines. And depending on the arrangement of multiple cards, you could also try aligning the texts itself to the centre. Should add a little 'cool' to the look.